# FileUpload.HasFile is always false, no update panel, worked until today

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a hair pulling issue on some code that is getting close to production. I have a file upload on a form that allows the user to attach documents to comments they post on an order within the system.

This FileUpload control is not in an Update Panel, and never was. It worked up until today. I was testing the project and realized the files weren't uploading, and found out that `.hasfile` just started returning false for everything, seemingly overnight as I have database records, with an uploaded file from days prior.

This is the section of the form button click that uploads the file, if one is in the fileupload

```
if (fileUp.HasFile)
{
            String mime = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileUp.FileName);
            String name = fileUp.FileName;
            byte[] bytes = fileUp.FileBytes;
            sql = "INSERT INTO orderAttachments (orderID, noteID, mimeType, theUpload, isDeleted, addedDateTime, addedIP, submittedBy, isBuyingOffice, commentID) VALUES (@id, @name, @mime, @doc, @del, GETDATE(), @ip, @assName, @buy, @commID)";
            cmd.CommandText = sql;               
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mime", mime);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc", bytes);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@del", 0);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assName", ad.FirstName() + " " + ad.LastName());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@buy", b);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commID", commid);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
```

}

This is the comment form

```
<ul id="commentbox" class="flex-box" visible="true" runat="server">
                        <li>
                            <label>Add Comment To Order</label></li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="commentTb" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Attach File: </label>
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUp" runat="server" /></li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="boCb" runat="server" Text="Restrict To Buying Office" /></li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Button ID="commentBtn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="commentBtn_Click" /></li>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RcommentVl" runat="server" ControlToValidate="commentTb" ErrorMessage="Comment Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </ul>
```

Can anyone explain, or help gives some insight on to why this may be happening without using an update panel (I can only find answers with that). Also, my files aren't empty, they are the same test files I've been using and have confirmed they have data.

Comment: Does your file have any text in it?

Comment: @HastaTamang yes, It says that at the bottom of the post

Comment: Sorry must be tiredness did not spot that in your question. Does your form has runat="server"? Looking at the [source code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/UI/WebControls/FileUpload@cs/1/FileUpload@cs) it might be missing the `HttpPostedFile` which could be the case if  `Page != null && Page.IsPostBack`

Comment: the form has `runat=server`, and I don't understand what you mean by the HttpPostedFile, could you explain please?

Comment: When you upload a file, behind the scenes it is the `HttpPostedFile` which has your actual file. If you did `HttpPostedFile myFile = Context.Request.Files[fileUp];` before `fileUp.HasFile` does it get populated? If not check if your configuration like httpRuntime for example

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I found the issue, and still don't understand how this actually caused the problem. I'm going to post it as an answer, and maybe someone will be able to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found my issue, but it raises more questions than answers.

I had added an invisible, second form to the page, with a placeholder like this.

```
<form ID="form2" runat="server" visible="false">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" Visible="false" runat="server"> 


        </asp:PlaceHolder> 
</form>
```

This was at the bottom of the page, and was only visible during a very rare condition that would have been used by an administrator (the main form's visibility would have been set to false when this appeared). When it was visible buttons were added to the placeholder based on some criteria.

Anyway,  I deleted this and moved it to its own aspx page, and `FileUpload.HasFile` started showing as `true` again when it should have been.

Does anyone know why this may have caused `FileUpload.HasFile` to always show false?

Comment: The short answer is that things go wrong in asp.net with more than 1 form on the page. I don't know all the details.